# convergent sequence / prove of reordering rule

Tags: sequences-and-series

Could someone show me please how to solve the following question?

Prove/show or disprove the following reordering rule:

If $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a convergent sequence and $\pi : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is a bijective function, then

$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{\pi(n)}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $\pi$ is a bijection, what is the following limit?
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\pi(n)
$$

You can show that it must be infinite.  Because $(a_n)$ is convergent, for any $\epsilon$ you can find an $N$ such that $\lvert a_n-a\rvert<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$, where $a=\lim a_n$. Now, can you somehow find an $M$ such that $\pi(n)\geq N$ whenever $n\geq M$?

Comment: hmm...thank you Nicholas for you hint. But I still dont get it. Maybe you can show me what $M$ might be and I try somehow to underpin it with context. Because right now is just quite dark :(

Comment: What does it mean to say that $\pi(n)\to\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: they both converge on $a \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I didn't ask you anything at all about $a$ or $a_n$.  Just literally: what is the definition of the phrase "$\pi(n)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$"?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I somehow stuggle to understand the formal definition of a convergent sequence.

Comment: To say that $\pi(n)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ means that for any $N$, there exists an $M$ such that $\pi(n)\geq N$ whenever $n\geq M$.  In other words: for any number ($N$), we can go far enough along the sequence ($n\geq M$) to make $\pi(n)$ exceed that number.

Comment: $(a_n)$ is convergent, for any $\epsilon$ you can find an $N$ such that $\lvert a_n-a\rvert<\epsilon$ this is the part which a dont get. Sorry for my slowness, but can you tell me the role of $\epsilon$

Comment: You are asked to show that $a_{\pi(n)}$ converges to $a$.  By definition, that means "For any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $M$ such that $\lvert a_{\pi(n)}-a\rvert<\epsilon$ whenever $n\geq M$.

Comment: yes thx, this is the issue i dont get the definion...is there a way to draw a simple example to understand: "For any $\epsilon$ >0  there is an $M$ such that  $\lvert a_n-a\rvert<\epsilon$ whenever $n > N(\epsilon)$

Comment: If your issue here is with the definitions, I strongly suggest you schedule some time with your instructor. That sort of intuition is much easier to communicate in real time, in person.

Answer (score 2):

Define $a=\lim{n\to\infty}a_n$.

Be $\epsilon > 0$. Since $(a_n)$ is convergent, there exists an $N\in\mathbb N$ so that $\left|a_n-a\right|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$. Since there are only finitely many natural numbers $\le N$, there exists $N' = \max\{\pi^{-1}(n):n\le N\}$. Then for every $n>N'$, we have $\pi(n)>N$, and therefore $\left|a_{\pi(n)}-a\right|<\epsilon$. Thus $(a_{\pi(n)})$ also converges to $a$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this assertion is correct. A proof is:

For $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(a_{\pi(n)})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, since $\pi$ is bijective, we can conclude that

$\varlimsup_{n} a_n=\varlimsup_{n} a_{\pi(n)}$ and also $\varliminf_{n} a_n=\varliminf_{n} a_{\pi(n)}$.

We already know that $\varlimsup_{n} a_n=\varliminf_{n} a_n$, so $\varlimsup_{n} a_{\pi(n)}=\varliminf_{n} a_{\pi(n)}$.

Conclusion follows.

Comment: Your third line is at least as difficult to prove/disprove as the OP's question and, in fact, for a converging sequence it is equivalent. I can't see how this can help in this case.

Comment: @DonAntonio I believe it's the case since I think the sup(resp. inf) limit of a sequence is free of the change of order, but now I can't find a right way to show it.

Comment: The "free of change of order" thing could be *also* said about the limit of the original sequence, @Xucheng Zhang....unless you prove otherwise. I think it is a perfectly circular argument here.

Comment: @DonAntonio Um...it's really a problem.